# iOS 8 - show incoming call when app is not active (without CallKit)

Tags: ios, background, ios8, voip, pushkit

I received incoming call requests using PushKit/VoIP. The problem is I cannot launch the app to show incoming call screen since CallKit is not available prior to iOS 10. 
I have succeeded to show notifications but how can I launch the app from background?

Here is my code:

```
 func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {
    if (pushCredentials.type == .voIP) {
        let pkToken = (pushCredentials.token as NSData).description
        SocketManager.shared.send(pkToken: pkToken)
    }
}


func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType) {
    let payloadDict = payload.dictionaryPayload["aps"] as? Dictionary<String, String>
    let message = payloadDict?["alert"]


    Notifications.present(id: "test", title: "test", body: message)
    NSLog("incoming voip notfication 1: \(payload.dictionaryPayload)")
}
```

Comment: Prior to iOS 10 you will need the user to tap the notification or your app icon to launch your app.

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11

Comment: My app did not lunched automatically when voip notification comes in ios 10 *